# Why does addition not work with this code?

Tags: java, android, calculator

I am new to AndroidStudio. I have managed appending numbers and digits but can't make an addition.

```
buttonEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText numbers = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numbers);
            int ans = 0;
            String str1;
            String str2;
            if (numbers.toString().contains("+")){
                str1 = numbers.toString().substring(0, numbers.toString().indexOf('+'));
                str2 = numbers.toString().substring(numbers.toString().indexOf('+') + 1, 
                numbers.length());
                ans = Integer.parseInt(str1) + Integer.parseInt(str2);
                numbers.setText(Integer.toString(ans));
            }

        }
    });
```

This is my code for the addition part (haven't tried other operations yet), when I press Enter, the app does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting the text from the `EditText`. Add the following method at `numbers` before you do the filtering:

```
numbers.getText()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line of code `numbers.toString().contains("+")` with this `numbers.getText().toString().contains("+")`